# How to aquire two different results from a qr scan

Tags: java, android

so i need to aquire a result for when i scan using the login button and another result when i scan using the logout button. This because they are supposed to update 2 different tables(signIn and sigOut tables)

```
 try {
        Button scanner = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signInBtn);
        scanner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }

        });

        Button scanner2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signoutBtn);
        scanner2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent1.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
            }

        });

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Log.e("onCreate", "Scanner Not Found", anfe);
        getClass();
    }

    list= (Button) findViewById(R.id.lookup_btn);
    list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your this two line in your code

```
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and

```
 startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);
```

and put changes in onActivityResult according to result

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Just don't know how i missed that